# Why in bubble sort I get number of swaps (instead of Zero) when I try to enter a sorted array?

Tags: java, bubble-sort

```js
> Bubble `BUUBLE

> Sorting
**SWAPING**

`
       import java.util.Random;

        public class bubble {
**Initializing**
  public static int count1 = 0;
  public static int swap = 0;

  public static int[][] Bubbles(int[] a) {
    int output[] = new int[2];
    for (int pass = 0; pass < a.length; pass++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        count1++;
        if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
          int temp = a[i];
          a[i] = a[i + 1];
          a[i + 1] = temp;
          swap++; 

        }
      }
    }
    output[0] = swap;
    output[1] = count1;

    return new int[][] {
      a,
      output
    };
  }
}


Bubble sort **Bubble**
```

Comment: I ran your code on a sorted array and got `swap = 0`...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your input array is sorted in ascending or descending order. If your input array is ordered like so: {10, 9, 8, ...} then a[0] > a[1], and you will enter the if-then construct in the nested for loop, incrementing swap. As a result, you will have a non-zero value for swap.